# update dictionary with dynamic keys and values in python

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.x, key

I have a dictionary and I want to insert keys and values dynamically but I didn't manage to do it. The problem is that when I use the update method it doesn't add a pair but it deletes the previous values so I have only the last value when printing the dictionary 
here is my code

```
i = 0
for o in iterload(f):
    i=i+1
    mydic = {i : o["name"]}
    mydic.update({i : o["name"]})
    for k, v in mydic.items():
        print(k,v) 
print(mydic)
```

f is a file that  i'm parsing with python code 
as a result I get

```
{3: 'toto'}
```

which is the last element. is there a solution to have all the elements in my dictionary

Thanks in advance

I have another question

Now I need to chek if an input value equals a key from my dictionary and if so I need to get the value of this key to continue parsing the file and get other informations.

Here is my code :

```
f = open('myfile','r')
nb_name = input("\nChoose the number of the name :")

for o in iterload(f):
    if o["name"] == mydic[nb_name]: 
        ...
```

I get a keyError

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../test.py", line 37, in <module>
            if o["name"] == mydic[nb_name]: 
KeyError: '1'
```

I don't understand the problem

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Remove the following line:

```
    mydic = {i : o["name"]}
```

and add the following before your loop:

```
mydic = {}
```

Otherwise you're creating a brand new one-element dictionary on every iteration.

Also, the following:

```
mydic.update({i : o["name"]})
```

is more concisely written as

```
mydic[i] = o["name"]
```

Finally, note that the entire loop can be rewritten as a dictionary comprehension:

```
mydic = {i+1:o["name"] for i,o in enumerate(iterload(f))}
```

Comment: you could pass `start=1` to `enumerate()` to match code from the question without `i+1`

Answer (score 4):

You could use `len()` to insert the value:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

queue = {}

queue[len(queue)] = {'name_first': 'Jon', 'name_last': 'Doe'}
queue[len(queue)] = {'name_first': 'Jane', 'name_last': 'Doe'}
queue[len(queue)] = {'name_first': 'J', 'name_last': 'Doe'}

print queue
```

Answer (score 1):

[@NPE pointed out the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13860049/4279) in your code (redefining the dict on each iteration).

Here's one more way to generate the dict (Python 3 code):

```
from operator import itemgetter

mydict = dict(enumerate(map(itemgetter("name"), iterload(f)), start=1))
```

---

About the `KeyError: '1'`: `input()` returns a string in Python 3 but the dictionary `mydict` expects an integer. To convert the string to integer, call `int`:

```
nb_name = int(input("\nChoose the number of the name :"))
```

Comment: Why do you say this is python 3 code?  I don't see any reason for it to fail with python 2... although, I might write it as: `dict(enumerate((x['name'] for x in iterload(f)),start=1))`, or possibly moving the `enumerate`:  `dict((i,x['name]) for i,x in enumerate(iterload(f),start=1))`.  I replaced `map` with a generator expression.  In python3, this is the same thing, but this will do exactly the same thing in python3 and python2 -- and I think it is a little easier to read.

Comment: @mgilson: `map` returns a list in Python 2. To make it Python 2 code you could add `from itertools import imap as map`. For readability I would use the dict comprehension from @NPE's answer.

Comment: I'm aware that map would return a list in py2k.  But the code would probably still work (unless the file is huge) -- in which case, storing the data in a dict might not work either.  The dict-comprehension is nice, but it imposes a python2.7 minimum.  My version with `dict` is an attempt to meet a happy medium -- generators that behave like your `map`, but work for python2.x and IMHO are more easy to read + using the `dict` constructor to create the dict in a way that is compatible with older python versions.  (and it really doesn't read much different than the dict-comp)